Argument principle vs Stieltjes integral
In complex analysis, Suppose $f: D\to \mathbb{C}$ is meromorphic on domain $D$ and $\Gamma:[0,1]\to D$ is a smooth closed curve contained in $D$, where $f\circ \Gamma\neq 0$. Then using residue theorem, we have $\int_{\Gamma}\frac{f'}{f}dz=N(0)-N(\infty)$, where the RHS are number of zeros and poles times there multiplcities, respectively, inside cirve $\Gamma$. What I'm trying to ask is whether I understand the $log$-interpretation of the integral correctly.
So, suppose we fix a branch of the $log$ function, in essence fixing a branch of $Arg$ function. Then, $\frac{f'}{f}=\left(log f\right)'$, and so, for a small interval $[a,b]\subset [0,1]$ where $log (f\circ \Gamma)$ has no discontinuities, integral $\int_{\Gamma|_{[a,b]}}\frac{f'}{f}dz=log(f\circ\Gamma)|_a^b$ can be computed as usual with no issues. So, we can partition $[0,1]$ into $0=a_0< \cdots < a_{m+1}=1$ with all the discontinuities $a_i$'s of function $$log(f\circ\Gamma)=log|f\circ\Gamma|+i Arg(f\circ\Gamma).$$
Thus,
$$\int_{\Gamma}\frac{f'}{f}dz=\int_{[0,1]}\left(log f\circ \Gamma\right)'dt=\sum_{i=0}^m\int_{[a_i, a_{i+1}]}d\left(log (f\circ \Gamma)\right)=2\pi i m', \text{ for some integer }m'\leq m.$$

Question. Is my interpretation above correct? That is, we disregard the jump of function $log(f\circ\Gamma)$ at discontinuities $a_i$'s, in contrast to how the Riemann-Stieltjes integral $\int_{[0,1]}d\left(log f\circ \Gamma\right)$ is defined, where the jumps contribute to the value of the integral?

Hope it's not too silly. Thanks in advance.
Update. It seems it comes down to the following

If $g: [0,1]\to \mathbb{C}$ is discontinuous with jumps at finitely many points
$$a_1<\cdots<a_m\in (0,1)$$
while differentiable on every open interval $(a_i, a_{i+1})$. Then
$$\int_0^1 g'dt= g(1)-g(0)-\sum_{i=1}^m \left(g(a_i^+)-g(a_i^-)\right)$$

In case $g:= \log (f\circ \Gamma)$, we have $g'=\frac{f'}{f}\Gamma'$,$g(0)=g(1)$ and every $J_i:= g(a_i^+)-g(a_i^-)=-2\pi i$. Hence $\int_{\Gamma}\frac{f'}{f}dz=\int_0^1\frac{f'}{f}\Gamma'dt=\int_0^1 g'dt=0-(-2\pi i m)=2\pi im$.

If one ignored the jumps of the log function in the integration, the result value for the inegral would be $0$ by the FTC, since the integration begins and ends at the same point. It is exactly because those jumps are not being ignored that the integral is assigned a non-zero value.

@PaulSinclair So $\sum_{i=0}^m\left(g(a_{i+1}^{-1}) - g(a_{i}^+)\right)=2\pi i m'$, where integer $m'$ can be determined by argument principle. The FTC cannot be directly applied to the whole integral $\int_{[0,1]}g'dt$ when $g$ has discontinuous jumps inside $(0,1)$.

That is exactly my point. Ingoring those points would mean treating the integration as if it could be calculated from the FTC. But doing so gives $0$, while the values provided are not $0$. The fact that they are not $0$ means that no, the discontinuities were not ignored. They are exactly where the value comes from.

@PaulSinclair What is ignored are the jumps $J_i:=g(a_{i}^+)-g(a_{i}^-)$. These are not the same as $I_i:=g(a_{i+1}^-)-g(a_i^+)$. The latter is the result of FTC applied to $\int_{a_i}^{a_{i+1}}g'dt$ on issue-free small intervals $(a_i, a_{i+1})$. My point is the sum $\sum_i I_i\neq 0$!

@PaulSinclair My point is the correct value is $\sum_i I_i$, and it's neither $0$ (in general) nor $g(1)-g(0)$, but $\sum_i I_i=\left[g(1)-g(0)\right]-\sum_i J_i$. That's what I mean by "jumps $J_i$'s being ignored".

@PaulSinclair It seems we are actually saying the same thing, just from opposite directions...
